# Using API Interface in Class Library, and the Class Library in API Interface?

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2019, class-library, webapi

My Project kind of looks like this:

```
Solution 
|-> Continent.Data (Class Library)
      ContinentRepository.cs
   
|-> ContinentsApi (WebApi)
      ContinentController.cs
      IContinentRepository.cs
      Continent.cs
```

My problem is that I need the ContinentsApi to use the Continent.Data, but also need Continent.Data to use ContinentsApi.

Comment: What is the `ContinentRepositor` library? We don't know anything about that, so please give context. And what does "can't" mean exactly? What did you try? What went wrong? What specific issue are you facing? More information and clarity is needed before we can help you properly. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need further guidance on how to ask a question which will be well-received and easy to answer. Thanks.

Comment: You need an instance of the class not the Class name.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the API project? Is your interface marked `public`? Details about what "can't" specifically means would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't implement the IContinentRepository or use the Continent class in the Class Library ContinentRepository

If I understand you correctly, you effectively want to do this:

```
public class ContinentRepository : IContinentRepository
{
    public Continent GetById(int id) {}
}
```

but you're unable to because your class library doesn't have access to either `Continent` or `IContinentRepository`. This could be fixed by referencing your API project from your class library. However, there is a problem. In order to be able to make use of your `ContinentRepository`, you need to be able to either construct instances of it in your API project or register the implementation with a DI container. To fix that, the API project would need to reference the class library to have access to `ContinentRepository`, and so we come to the real problem: circular references.

What you're trying to do is possible, but the part you're missing is your `Domain` project - another class library, one that shouldn't reference any other project in your solution. This is where you define your interfaces and business logic. In your example, `Continent` and `IContinentRepository` are both part of your domain, so they should live in your `Domain` project. The solution structure then looks like this:

```
 Solution 
 |-> Continent.Data (Class Library)
       ContinentRepository.cs
 |
 |
\|/ (Continent.Data references Domain)

 |-> Contintent.Domain (Class Library)
       IContinentRepository.cs
       Continent.cs

/|\  (ContinentsApi references Domain)
 |
 |
 |-> ContinentsApi (WebApi)
       ContinentController.cs
```

Here `ContinentsApi` is considered to be your solution's [composition root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) where dependency graphs are created. There should be only one composite root. As a result, `ContinentsApi` would also reference `Continent.Data` so that you can construct, or register with a DI container, your implementations in your `Continent.Data` project.

The `Domain` project removes the circular reference problem, thus solving your issue.

To add references to other projects:

- Right-click the project you want to add a reference to
- Go to `Add` -> `Project Reference...`
- Check the box next to the project you want to reference
- Click `OK`

Alternatively, you can do this faster if you right-click on `Dependencies` in a .NET Core project, or `References` in a .NET Framework project, both of which can be found just under the project in your solution. This is a picture of where you'll find it in a .NET Core project:

[image: Project dependencies in solution explorer]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was having a hard time understanding the problem and couldn't find a solution, but now I understand and will adapt the project!